# Roundcube SSL connection IMAP Error: Login failed. Problem with my certificate ssl?

Tags: ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt, mail-server, dovecot

today  haved a issues with the conection in my mailserver, when I try to login can't access.

The error says:

```
IMAP Error: Login failed for user@myserver.com against host.myserver.com from IP_ADDRESS. Could not 
connect to ssl://host.myserver.com:993: Unknown reason in 
../lib/Roundcube/rcube_imap.php on line 200 (POST /webmail/?_task=login&_action=login)
```

When Try to check my ssl certificate with this command, received this response:

```
openssl s_client -connect xxxxxx.xxxx:993
140150541821056:error:0200206E:system library:connect:Connection timed out:../crypto/bio/b_sock2.c:110:
140150541821056:error:2008A067:BIO routines:BIO_connect:connect error:../crypto/bio/b_sock2.c:111:
connect:errno=110
```

I'm not sure for what happened this. I created the certificate and actually I access to my web behind this domain.

Can you help me with this? Thanks a lot of!!!

Comment: Try https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/getting-started-guide/internet-and-networking/troubleshooting-ssl-connections-with-the-openssl-program.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will check